# How do I trigger a custom method in a Redactor plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redactor

The following jQuery plugin has an API where you can add your own methods.

Here is [a simple example](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/creatingplugins/).

In the example on that page, how would I call the function `your_method`?

They don't show this. All I want to do is put a button on the page and then when that button is clicked, trigger off my own custom method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create an init method in which you can create a button on a toolbar and bind your custom plugin method to it:

```
RedactorPlugins.myPlugin = {

    init: function() {
        this.addBtn('myMethod', 'MyMethod', function(obj) {
            obj.myMethod();
        });
    },

    myMethod: function() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really wanting to use the editor / toolbar in this instance. I want to have a stand alone button on the page ('Upload') and then trigger the upload functionality from Redactor.

Comment: so you would like to invoke fileUpload/imageUpload from outside of the Redactor itself?

Comment: I'm not sure it's included in the official API but if you don't mind having a small hack, then you can hide the upload button on the toolbar $("a.redactor_btn_file").hide(); and click on it from wherever you like $("a.redactor_btn_file").click(); this is ugly though...

Comment: Thanks, yeah I do want to invoke it outside of a redactor text editor - I want to use the coolness of the upload function. To give context, it's to allow someone to upload a 'feature image' so there is no text area in this case, just an image field.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
if (!RedactorPlugins) var RedactorPlugins = {};

RedactorPlugins.myPlugin = function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
        },
        myMethod: function() {
            alert ("method");
        }
    };
};

$("#redactor").redactor({
    plugins: ['myPlugin']
});


$("#redactor").redactor("myPlugin.myMethod");
```

or you can add it to a click event on something else

```
$(".selector").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#redactor").redactor("myPlugin.myMethod");
});
```

Comment: `$("#redactor").redactor("myPlugin.myMethod");` - this works for standalong buttons, thanks!